# Use username as email, Spring Security UI plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I'm using the Spring Security plugin, in combination with the Spring Security UI plugin.

They both work like a charm, but my problem is that I don't want my user to have a username, instead he/she should use the e-mail as username.

So in the register-phase I tried removing the username from the registration-page and setting

```
newUser.username = params.email
```

So that the plugins still can access the variable username, but this gave me validation errors and I just can't figure out a way to solve it.

Any ideas? Has anyone done anything similar?

Comment: What kind of validation error do you get?

Comment: This is the first error I get: "Field error in object 'grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.RegisterCommand' on field 'username': rejected value [null];"
When I try to do try to set the email by doing user.username = params.email (getting the email from the params) I still get the same.

Comment: well.. the error message says that `username` is `null`. So you should make sure there is a valid email in `params.email`

Comment: Yes I understand that, but even if I print out the params after setting the username to the email it fails. When I validate the domain class I still get that error.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the default User field that spring security uses

In your **Config.groovy** add the following

> grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'XXX'

where XXX is the field of the User entity to be used

You can check the configuration attributes [here](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#4.1%20Person%20Class)

Comment: AAA-grade link! Sounds reasonable, but as I'm using the UI plugin, there are some internal classes e.g. RegistrationCommand, that use "username". It's also used in forgot password and account confirmation.

Perhaps I should just remove every trace of username but what I'm afraid of is that something somewhere expects that username should exist.

Comment: Most probable you already have seen [this](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Using-spring-security-UI-with-customized-user-class-td2330737.html), there are same code samples in this (outdated) thread about how to use spring security UI with customized user class.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done this by copying views and controllers from spring security plugin to my grails-app and updated view to display emailAddress as oppose to username. I also replaced username property with emailAddress in User domain class. Make sure you update the constrains as follows:

```
static constraints = {
    emailAddress email: true, blank: false, unique: true
    password blank: false, password: true
}
```

What [dimcookies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1263838/dimcookies) suggest is correct and works for old version of Grails, the new syntax configuration, at least for Grails 2.3.1, is:

`grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'emailAddress'`